# type inference in fold left one-liner?

Tags: scala, type-inference, fold

I was trying to reverse a List of Integers as follows:

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(List[Int]()){(a,b) => b::a}
```

My question is that is there a way to specify the seed to be some `List[_]` where the `_` is the type automatically filled in by scala's type-inference mechanism, instead of having to specify the type as `List[Int]`?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any practical reason for this? What is the context? Because `List[_]` is just 2 characters shorter than `List[Int]`. And to reverse a list, you would use `.reverse` anyway.

Comment: No practical reason, just a weird itch to know the limitations of scala's type inference system

Comment: Ok. Based on this, I posted a theoretical answer and not a work-around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** After reading a bit more on Scala's type inference, I found a better answer to your question. [This article](http://pchiusano.blogspot.ch/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html) which is about the limitations of the Scala type inference says:

> Type information in Scala flows from function arguments to their results [...], **from left to right across argument lists**, and from first to last across statements. This is in contrast to a language with full type inference, where (roughly speaking) type information flows unrestricted in all directions.

So the problem is that Scala's type inference is rather limited. It *first* looks at the first argument list (the list in your case) and *then* at the second argument list (the function). But it does not go back.

This is why neither this

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(Nil){(a,b) => b::a}
```

nor this

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(List()){(a,b) => b::a}
```

will work. Why? First, the signature of `foldLeft` is defined as:

```
 foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

So if you use `Nil` as the first argument `z`, the compiler will assign `Nil.type` to the type parameter `B`. And if you use `List()`, the compiler will use `List[Nothing]` for `B`.

Now, the type of the second argument `f` is fully defined. In your case, it's either

```
(Nil.type, Int) => Nil.type
```

or

```
(List[Nothing], Int) => List[Nothing]
```

And in both cases the lambda expression `(a, b) => b :: a` is not valid, since its return type is inferred to be `List[Int]`.

---

Note that the bold part above says "argument lists" and not "arguments". The article later explains:

> Type information does not flow from left to right *within* an argument list, only from left to right *across* argument lists.

So the situation is even worse if you have a method with a single argument list.

Comment: Incredible - It makes much more sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know how is

```
scala> def foldList[T](l: List[T]) = l.foldLeft(List[T]()){(a,b) => b::a}
foldList: [T](l: List[T])List[T]

scala> foldList(List(1,2,3,4))
res19: List[Int] = List(4, 3, 2, 1)

scala> foldList(List("a","b","c"))
res20: List[java.lang.String] = List(c, b, a)
```